# Custom logger channel doesn't print in production in symfony 2.7

Tags: symfony, logging

I am trying to print a custom channel in production. It works great in the dev environment.  I want it to log at all times and not just on error.

Below is my config for production:

```
monolog:
channels: ["always"]
handlers:
    main:
        type:         fingers_crossed
        action_level: error
        handler:      nested
        channels: ["!always"]
    nested:
        type:  stream
        path:  "%kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%.log"
        level: debug
    console:
        type:  console
    always:
        type: stream
        path:   "%kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%.log"
        level:  debug
        channels: ['always']
```

This is my config for development:

```
monolog:
channels: ["always"]
handlers:
    main:
        type:   stream
        path:   "%kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%.log"
        level:  debug
        channels: ["!always"]
    console:
        type:   console
        bubble: false
        verbosity_levels:
            VERBOSITY_VERBOSE: INFO
            VERBOSITY_VERY_VERBOSE: DEBUG
        channels: ["!doctrine"]
    console_very_verbose:
        type:   console
        bubble: false
        verbosity_levels:
            VERBOSITY_VERBOSE: NOTICE
            VERBOSITY_VERY_VERBOSE: NOTICE
            VERBOSITY_DEBUG: DEBUG
        channels: ["doctrine"]
    always:
        type: stream
        path:   "%kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%.log"
        level:  debug
        channels: always
```

here is an example from the log:

```
[2017-01-23 14:17:39] always.INFO: STAR REMOTE CONTROL FROM DEFAULT CONTROLLER [] []
```

and Here is how I call it:

```
  /**
   * @param Request $request
   * @return Response
   * @throws \Exception
   * @Route("/star-remote-control")
   *
   */
  public function starRemoteControlAction(Request $request)
  {
    $this->container->get('monolog.logger.always')->info('STAR REMOTE CONTROL FROM DEFAULT CONTROLLER');
    ...
```

Can you help me troubleshoot why it is not showing up in the prod.log?

Answer (score 0):

check out the [official documentation about the fingers_crossed handler](http://symfony.com/doc/current/logging.html#handlers-that-modify-log-entries):

> It stores all log messages during a request but only passes them to a second handler if one of the messages reaches an action_level.

Your action level in **prod** environment is error, but you are actually logging a **info** message. Try changing the action level or log and **error** or **critical** message and the entry should show up in the **prod** log file.

Answer (score 0):

So the answer to my problem was really all about the order of the handlers.  All I has to do was move the "Always" handler to the top before the "fingers_crossed" handler and the logs were written exactly as I wanted them.

Here is the config_prod.yml

```
monolog:
channels: ["always"]
handlers:
    always:
        type: stream
        path:   "%kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%.log"
        level:  debug
        channels: ["always"]
    main:
        type:         fingers_crossed
        action_level: error
        handler:      nested
        channels: ["!always"]
    nested:
        type:  stream
        path:  "%kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%.log"
        level: debug
    console:
        type:  console
```

Comment: usually you do not want debug output in prod environment logs, so this is not the best way to solve your issue. Maybe it will work for you now but I guess you will need to redefine it once you make more progress in your project ;-)